# Merging two incomplete factors

Tags: r

I find myself in the following situation:

After merging four data sets over the same observations, I ended up with two variables coding the conditions, however these were done by different researchers and there are incompleteness in both. Please consider the MWE:

```
ID <- c("a1", "a2", "a3",  "a4", "a5", "a6")
a <- c("sch", "con", "unknown", "sch", "con", "con")
b <- c("sch", "con", "sim", "sch", "unknown", "con")


dt <- data.frame(ID, a, b)
dt
```

Prints out:

```
  ID       a       b
1 a1     sch     sch
2 a2     con     con
3 a3 unknown     sim
4 a4     sch     sch
5 a5     con unknown
6 a6     con     con
```

I want to create a new variable that complements whichever entry that was not completed, so to look like:

```
  ID       a       b     ab
1 a1     sch     sch     sch
2 a2     con     con     con
3 a3 unknown     sim     sim
4 a4     sch     sch     sch
5 a5     con unknown     con
6 a6     con     con     con
```

- How to achieve this in R? Is there also a way of checking inconsistencies between a and b as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could replace it with `NA` and then use `coalesce`

```
dt$ab <- do.call(dplyr::coalesce, replace(dt[-1], dt[-1] == 'unknown', NA))
```

Or using `pmax`

```
do.call(pmax, c(replace(dt[-1], dt[-1] == 'unknown', NA), list(na.rm = TRUE)))
#[1] "sch" "con" "sim" "sch" "con" "con"
```

#### data

```
dt <- data.frame(ID, a, b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```